# Setting up hardware accelerated Android emulation (HAXM) on Fedora or other RPM distributions?

Tags: hardware-acceleration

I'm doing Android development, and the emulation is (unsurprisingly) slow.  I see there's some documentation for setting up hardware acceleration (Intel HAXM) at 
http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/speeding-up-the-android-emulator-on-intel-architecture

This documentation covers installation for Windows and Linux, but for Linux it's Ubuntu specific - has anyone had success with setting this up on Fedora, or other recent RPM-based distro?

Answer (score 7):

I've got this working on a Fedora 19 install, it's straightforward and worthwhile...

## Install virtualization

This is documented at https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Getting_started_with_virtualization

install package group "virtualization"

```
sudo yum install @virtualization
```

this installs packages virt-install, libvirt, libvirt-daemon-kvm, qemu-kvm, virt-manager, virt-viewer and deps

---

## Start KVM and test

```
$ sudo systemctl start libvirtd
```

(if your distro uses the *service* command rather than new-fangled *systemctl*, you'll want use that to start libvirtd instead)

Verify that the kvm kernel modules were properly loaded:

```
$ lsmod | grep kvm
kvm_amd                55563  0 
kvm                   419458  1 kvm_amd
```

You can also verify using the virsh management tool

```
$ sudo virsh list
```

this gives an empty list e.g.

```
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
```

You may need to log out & log back in.

## Running the hardware accelerated device

I then tried starting a virtual device (having first downloaded an x86 system image using the SDK manager) and it seemed fast (started in ~10 seconds, and UI is snappy).  However the loading dialog didn't display the *"HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode"* message specified by the Intel docs.  Don't be disheartened; it's a nice thing to see not an end in itself.

## Finesse

Running on the command line showed an error message.  You can run the emulator on the command line in the SDK/tools directory, specifying the AVD name (same as you'll see in the virtual device manager):

```
[path/to/SDK/tools]$ ./emulator64-x86 -avd <AVD name>Nexus_S_4.0.3_x86 -qemu -m 2047 -enable-kvm
```

e.g.

```
[path/to/SDK/tools]$ ./emulator64-x86 -avd Nexus_S_4.0.3_x86 -qemu -m 2047 -enable-kvm
```

this returned the error

```
emulator: ERROR: Could not load OpenGLES emulation library: lib64OpenglRender.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
```

this can be fixed by adding the tools/lib directory to LD_LIBRARY_PATH
e.g. by running as

```
[path/to/SDK/tools]$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path/to/sdk/tools/lib ./emulator64-x86 -avd Nexus_S_4.0.3_x86  -qemu -m 2047 -enable-kvm
```

---

## Summary

I'm *very* pleased with how fast this is, and it's well worth the trouble.  The emulator starts in 6 seconds on my unspectacular desktop, and runs as nicely as the real hardware.